# Service stopping unexpectedly probably due to GC on Timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer, garbage-collection

My company has developed a Windows Service Application and it was installed in some customers.
They are complaining that the Service stops after continuously running for a few days.

I can't reproduce the error and I do not have any stack trace. All I have is a generic message in Event Viewer:

> The 'myservicename' service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s).

My code:

```
private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
private readonly Queue<FileInfo> MyQueue = new Queue<FileInfo>();

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 60 * 1); // 1 min
   myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyMethod);
   myTimer.Start();

   SomeSafeTasks();

   try
   {
      CreateSomeThreads();
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
      //log
   }
}

public void MyMethod()
{
   lock (MyQueue) // there are other places with lock
   {
      if(MyQueue.Count == 0)
      {
         // code with try catch
      }
   }
}
```

I believe that the error is related with the Timer being GC'ed.

1. Does it make sense? The code above may break after running some days?
2. How do I estimate when it will break? It is strange for me that it runs for a week. I would expect that it would be GC'ed in 15 minutes or 1 hour.
3. Is it 100% safe to add `GC.KeepAlive(myTimer)` after `myTimer.Start()`?
4. Will it run **forever** or do I need to call `GC.KeepAlive` sometimes?

Comment: Your timer is reachable via the private field. So this isn't a GC problem, not with the timer anyway. `GC.KeepAlive()` is always safe, but not needed here.

Comment: What happens in `myMethod`?

Comment: @Darek, it does some tasks. Probably safe tasks, but without a try/catch. If it breaks there, it could stop the whole service?

Comment: @Ricardo Yes, it will bubble up the exception all the way to the service, and since you have no un-handled exception handler, it will terminate the service.

Comment: Check your Windows Event Logs at the time the service terminates unexpectedly.  There could be exception information there.

Comment: Event Viewer shows only: The 'myservicename' service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 1 time(s).

Comment: Writing an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event and logging the exception is never really optional.  You are using a very dangerous timer, particularly with AutoReset = true, using try/catch in your Elapsed event handler is not optional either.

Comment: I concur @HansPassant :)

Comment: @HansPassant, why this is a very dangerous timer? Is there a better timer?